# Hyper-v VM shows 'Limited Connectivity' when using External Switch?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have been trying to setup a Win7 VM on Hyper-v that connects to the internet through my Win 8 host machine.

I can't seem to figure out why the VM can't ever get passed limited connectivity.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO sure why but all I had to do was Disable/enable the vEthernet adapter and everything worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a Virtual Switch with an "External Network" using the [Virtual Switch Manager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/create-a-virtual-switch-in-windows-8-client-hyper-v/).

The other network types offer VM isolation.  If your VM is on an "Private Network" it can only talk to other VMs on the server.  The "Internal Network" allows VMs can talk to other VMs and to the host.

In contrast, an External Network allows the VM to contact machines on the network that the host is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this issue for a while myself after upgrading to Windows 8.1 and losing connectivity. Added and removed the adapter to no avail. The solution was to upgrade the VM's Integration Services.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because my DHCP settings on my guest VM was setup wrong.

So check the DHCP setting if they are on obtain automatically.

Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections 
Network adapter properties -> Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) -> Properties ->
Obtain DNS server address automatically

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success with Hyper-V and windows 8 and windows 10 virtuals using external switches with a Windows 8.1 host.  Unfortunately I could not get the external switch to ever work on windows xp virtual running under Hyper-V.  Instead, after reading a lot of sites/suggestions, I followed this guide to bridge an internal virtual switch (with Hyper-V legacy network adapter for XP) to the host wifi.  I hope this saves someone else some time when working on an XP virtual.

[Using Hyper-V with a Wireless Network Adapter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/09/using-hyper-v-with-a-wireless-network-adapter.aspx)